# Programming vs usability questions?

Tags: discussion, migrate, questions

I saw [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/684/which-payment-provider-offers-the-best-user-experience) and found that this was more a programming / design than userbility / UI question.

I know design is a part of UI, but this question is more about branding and finding a technical solution than anything about a UI.

Should questions like this be moves to SO?

Comment: The question itself is UX-oriented. The discussion turned a bit programmy, but it still seems more suited for here than SO. There's definitely going to be some blur.

Answer (score 1):

I did not ask that question from a branding point of view, as branding is not relevant to me. What is relevant is whether users have a good experience, and therefore having my app's logo in place is important from a trust point of view. Secondly, I also asked this question on StackOverflow - but there, I did ask from a programming point of view. I took care to focus on the UX here, because this is the right place to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that questions like this should be moved to SO because:

1. At its heart it is a usability comparison question, so asking it can result in a listing of pros and cons of particular UI elements in this situation, which I think is fine for this site.
2. This question most certainly would get closed on SO because of its subjective nature, which I think is fine for *that* site, but not on this site.

Comment: I don't think it would necessarily get closed on SO if you paraphrased it to their context: "What is the best payment provider API?" and then explained in your question what your parameters were for "best". It's not that subjective; the "best" is going to be something that most people can agree on based on their experiences and overall adherence to things like design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the discussion went into programming land, because so many people are programmers.